# Tomcat 8.5 Basic authentication not working with correct username password

Tags: authentication, tomcat8

Here is my code and the credentials are not working on the pop-up shown on application load.please have a look

tomcat-users.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
        <role rolename="admin"/>
        <user username="admin" password="admin" role="admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

web.xml

```
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Web Application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Plus this Application is deployed on Heroku, so I might need help with this too

Comment: You have to uncomment the `UserDatabase` resource as well as `UserDatabaseRealm` in `server.xml`. These are already there in a fresh Tomcat install, but commented out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure codes are not commented.

Also add below line instead of < role rolename="admin"/>

< role rolename="admin-gui"/>

< role rolename="manager-gui"/>

< user username="admin" password="admin" role="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>

restart tomcat and then check

Comment: are you on the same machine where tomcat is installed or are you accessing it on other machine?

Comment: I have deployed my app on heroku. It prompts every time for credentials even if I provide the correct username and password

Comment: Tomcat version is 8.5.3

Comment: Browse to the location and open file using vi or vim editor: 

webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml and 

webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml 


Comment out the part of the configuration file specifying the IP address restriction or replace them with a list of IP addresses that you would like to whitelist.


<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <!--<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />-->
</Context>

Restart tomcat

Comment: Still not working.I have restarted my server as well

Comment: have you tried doing what i mentioned above?

I mean uncomment the Conext tag in context.xml file.

Comment: Yes i tried that too,still prompting for credentials

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167156/discussion-between-naushad-ahmad-and-samar).